# How to print a message, when error message is displayed on website selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Hi I am trying to scrape a website using selenium after sometime the website blocks my ip for scraping and a pop up message appears.

What i want to do is that whenever that pop up message appear it displays a warning on my terminal, My code looks like this to get the result

```
blo = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/h3')
if blo:
    print('ip blocked')
else:
    print('eroor')
```

But its not working i just get a blank screen, How can i solve this

HTML of the element:

```
<h3 class="modal-title">Notifications</h3>
<div class="alert alert-warning">Sorry, you have exceeded the maximum number of queries allowed per day. If you believe you have reached this message in error, please contact our support team.</div>
```

Comment: add wait for getting `blo` element. and if element, not fount then show your error

Comment: Nope didn't worked

Comment: `blo = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until( EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/h3')))` have you tried this ?

Comment: @walrus_run Please remember to mark the answer that solves your issue. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

The validate the presence of the *pop up message* you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  try:
      WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "h3.modal-title+div.alert.alert-warning")))
      print("ip blocked")
  except TimeoutException:
      print("eroor")
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  try:
      WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h3[@class='modal-title' and text()='Notifications']//following::div[@class='alert alert-warning']")))
      print("ip blocked")
  except TimeoutException:
      print("eroor")
  ```