# How can I print email address using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

```
<div id="MainCopy_ctl13_presentJob_EmailAddressPanel">
    <a id="MainCopy_ctl13_presentJob_EmailAddress" href="mailto:dburse@bjcta.org">xyzmmm@tccp.org</a>
</div>
```

I have tried using

```
email = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@id="MainCopy_ctl13_presentJob_EmailAddress"]//a').text
print(email)
```

But I'm not getting a result.

Comment: browser.find_elements_by_xpath why are using elements use browser.find_element_by_xpath  instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

text print only visible text use textContent attribute for text not in display port:

```
email = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="MainCopy_ctl13_presentJob_EmailAddressPanel"]//a').get_attribute("textContent")
print(email)
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'

Comment: @vamsi just change it to element updated the code , why were using elements

Comment: email = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="MainCopy_ctl13_presentJob_EmailAddress"]//a').get_attribute('textContent')

Comment: File "C:\Users\yyy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH

Comment: is it element  not found ?

Comment: @vamsi your id is wrong updated it MainCopy_ctl13_presentJob_EmailAddressPanel try now

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\jk\APTA\main.py", line 140, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\jk\APTA\main.py", line 61, in main
    email = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="MainCopy_ctl13_presentJob_EmailAddress"]//a').get_attribute('textContent')
  File "C:\Users\yyy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)

Comment: File "C:\Users\yyy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Users\yyy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)

Comment: File "C:\Users\yyy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@id="MainCopy_ctl13_presentJob_EmailAddress"]//a"}

Comment: you should use MainCopy_ctl13_presentJob_EmailAddressPanel i have updated the code please try that

Comment: Please accept the answer by clicking the tick sign near to my answer

Comment: Sure, can u help me with another one

Comment: browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="MainCopy_ctl13_presentJob_EmailAddressPanel"]//a').get_attribute("textContent")   how can we print 'no data' if email address is not present in that xpath

Comment: a =browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="MainCopy_ctl13_presentJob_EmailAddressPanel"]//a').get_attribute("textContent") ; if (a==""){a="no data"} add an if condition

Comment: i tried getting error selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@id="MainCopy_ctl13_presentJob_EmailAddressPanel"]//a"}

Comment: i am using looping, for first one i dont have email address, for second one i have email address

Comment: inside loop add a if condition

Comment: email = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="MainCopy_ctl13_presentJob_EmailAddressPanel"]//a').get_attribute("textContent")
   if(email == ""):
    email = "No Email"

Answer (score 1):

The email inside the a tag is the href of the a tag so just do this:

### Using Selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
    
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading")


a_tag = driver.find_element_by_id('MainCopy_ctl13_presentJob_EmailAddress')
mail_link = a_tag.get_attribute("href")
mail_addrs = mail_link.split(':')[1]
print(mail_addrs)
```

### Using Beautifulsoup:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    
content=""" 
<div id="MainCopy_ctl13_presentJob_EmailAddressPanel">
    a id="MainCopy_ctl13_presentJob_EmailAddress" href="mailto:dburse@bjcta.org">xyzmmm@tccp.org</a>
</div>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
a_tag = soup.find(id='MainCopy_ctl13_presentJob_EmailAddress')
mail_link = a_tag.attrs['href']
mail_addrs = mail_link.split(':')[1]
print(mail_addrs)
```

Comment: in the place of content it is possible to store with xpath ot get element by id. i am details using xpath

Comment: So you want to find the email but using xpath instead of id?

Comment: i am using  browser.find_element_by_id('MainCopy_ctl13_presentJob_EmailAddress')

Comment: we no need to use content variable

Answer (score 0):

is the element already there? or perhaps code executed before the element is loaded by Selenium?

consider using wait :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading")
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement"))
    )
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: element present, just we need to print.

Comment: i have used chome web driver

Answer (score 0):

The `id` attribute which you have used i.e. `MainCopy_ctl13_presentJob_EmailAddress` belongs to the `<a>` tag instead of the `<div>`

To print the *email address* you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector` and `get_attribute()`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a#MainCopy_ctl13_presentJob_EmailAddress").get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using `xpath` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@id='MainCopy_ctl13_presentJob_EmailAddress']").text)
  ```

---

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the [visibility_of_element_located()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59644133/how-to-print-a-message-when-error-message-is-displayed-on-website-selenium/59646825#59646825) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a#MainCopy_ctl13_presentJob_EmailAddress"))).text)
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and `get_attribute()`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@id='MainCopy_ctl13_presentJob_EmailAddress']"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: how to return empty result Ex: no data if the xpath doesnot have data