# How to crawl the title of the page?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I don't know how to crawl the title of the page,below is my code(it's simple),but I have no idea where is wrong, if you have any idea please let me know,thank you.

[image]

[image]

```
from selenium import webdriver
url="https://sukebei.nyaa.si/?s=seeders&o=desc&p=1"
driver_path = "C:\\webdriver\\chromedriver.exe"
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path, options=option)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get(url)
print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/head/title").text)
```

Comment: driver.title returns title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To crawl the title of the page you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [`visibility_of_element_located()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59644133/how-to-print-a-message-when-error-message-is-displayed-on-website-selenium/59646825#59646825) for the `<table>` with *torrent-list* and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://sukebei.nyaa.si/?s=seeders&o=desc&p=1')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table.torrent-list")))
  print(driver.title)
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://sukebei.nyaa.si/?s=seeders&o=desc&p=1')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//table[contains(@class, 'torrent-list')]")))
  print(driver.title)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Browse :: Sukebei
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 1):

```
from selenium import webdriver
url="https://sukebei.nyaa.si/?s=seeders&o=desc&p=1"
driver_path = "C:\\webdriver\\chromedriver.exe"
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path, options=option)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get(url)
print(driver.title)
```