# How to convert windows IDs to human readable format using Selenium and Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, window-handles, webdriver-w3c-spec

I know that if I want to know the corresponding IDs of the windows I currently have open, I use the following sentence on Python:

```
current_windows = driver.window_handles
print(current_windows)
```

Output (suppose there were 2 windows opened):

```
['CDwindow-807A80F3D56E82E4A61529E5898AC71C', 'CDwindow-7CEAB7D7E9B701F6279C4B5C4AEE1A29']
```

And I also know that if I want to get the title of the current page in the driver, I use the following sentence on Python:

```
current_window = driver.title
print(current_window)
```

Output:

```
Google
```

However, these windows IDs can't be understood by a mortal like me, so how could improve the sentence above to get the title of those windows?

I mean, to get an output like this that contains all the titles of the current windows open in the driver:

```
['Google', 'Facebook']
```

Comment: I don't think that those hex values can be changed. However, you can always do `driver.title` to get the current window title. By looking at the code `return self.execute(Command.W3C_GET_CURRENT_WINDOW_HANDLE)['value']` it is suppose to return the hex value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [WebDriver Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver1/#get-window-handles) of [**Window Handle**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69961842/is-there-any-way-to-get-all-tab-titles-of-browser-without-switching/69962381#69962381):

[image: getwindowhandle]

[where](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver1/#dfn-window-handles),

> Each browsing context has an associated window handle which uniquely
> identifies it. This must be a String and must not be "current".
>
> The web window identifier is the string constant
> "window-fcc6-11e5-b4f8-330a88ab9d7f".

So the output of the following command:

```
current_windows = driver.window_handles
print(current_windows)
```

as:

```
['CDwindow-807A80F3D56E82E4A61529E5898AC71C', 'CDwindow-7CEAB7D7E9B701F6279C4B5C4AEE1A29']
```

is as per the specification and neither contains the [*page title*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66187310/how-to-crawl-the-title-of-the-page/66187846#66187846) information nor can be converted to any human readable format.

To retrieve the *page title* the only command is:

```
print(driver.title)
```

Comment: I see, so it seems that one viable solution is to iterate over that array of IDs, switching between every single window handle, apply `driver.title` and store the information in an array, for then returning to the first window handle.

Comment: yep, but try to keep the code for switching optimized :)